# Find the order of the intersection of two subrings $H$ and $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $H$ and $K$ be two subrings of a ring of order $294$, such that $o(H)=49$ and $o(K)=49.$ Then find the possible orders for $H\cap K$?

I don't know how to find the order of $H\cap K$. The counting principle I know from Herstein's book, for groups is- If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group, then $$o(HK)=\frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}.$$
So is there any similar counting principle for rings also? Can we use the above for this problem as well? If so, how do I know about the order of $HK$? Please help me with a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Are all rings unital?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Nothing about that is given in the question, so let's assume they are unital.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all rings are supposed to be unital:

Let $R$ be the ring with $294 = 6 \cdot 49$ elements. Knowing that $H$ and $K$ must be unital subrings of $R$, it follows that they have the same characteristic as $R$ (the equation $1+1+1+\cdots+1=0$ is the same in $H$, $K$, and $R$). We consider the possibilities on the characteristic:

- $R$ cannot have a characteristic which is not a factor of $49$, because the additive subgroup of $H$ generated by $1$ must have order $1$, $7$ or $49$, by Lagrange's theorem.
- If $R$ has characteristic $1$, then it is necessarily the trivial ring, so it has order $1$, which is a contradiction.
- If $R$ has characteristic $7$, then it is a vector space over $\mathbb F_7$, and must have order $7^d$ for some $d$. Contradiction.
- Exercise: $R$ cannot have characteristic $49$ either.

So the premise of the problem is impossible.

If the rings are allowed to be non-unital, then consider the fact that any additive abelian group $A$ can be made into a non-unital ring by defining $a \cdot b = 0$ for all $a, b \in A$. So the answer is the same as that for abelian groups.